# How to fixup all commits into first without entering interactive mode?

Tags: git, github

let's say I have this git commits

```
sha1 A
sha1 B
sha1 C
sha1 D
```

Is there any way to automate interactive mode rebase with fixup? I want to fixup all other commits to first one like this:

```
git rebase origin/branch -i 

pick sha1 A
fixup sha1 B
fixup sha1 C
fixup sha1 D
```

Can I do it single line without entering interactive mode?